# how to add dynamic filter in magento 2 admin ui components?

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, filter

> I want to filter the Magento 2 UI component based on
>
> $custom value in Magento 2

**how I can do the dynamic filters for Magento UI components?**

anyone have any idea

*listing_component.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_quotes_listing_data_source4</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_quotes_listing_data_source4</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">quick_quotes_columns</item>
        <!--<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Quote</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>-->
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="quick_quotes_listing_data_source4">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">QuoteGridDataProvider2</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">quick_quotes_listing_data_source4</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">quick_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">quick_quotes_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.quick_quotes_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_quotes_listing_data_source4</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.quick_quotes_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.quick_quotes_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterSelect name="store_id">
                <argument name="optionsProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options</argument>
                </argument>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
                        <item name="captionValue" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterSelect>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.quick_quotes_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">quick_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>

            <!--<action name="done">-->
            <!--    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
            <!--        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
            <!--            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">done</item>-->
            <!--            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Done</item>-->
            <!--            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="quick/index/massStatus/status/Done"/>-->
            <!--        </item>-->
            <!--    </argument>-->
            <!--</action>-->
            <!--<action name="new">-->
            <!--    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
            <!--        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
            <!--            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">new</item>-->
            <!--            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New</item>-->
            <!--            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="quick/index/massStatus/status/New"/>-->
            <!--        </item>-->
            <!--    </argument>-->
            <!--</action>-->
            <!--<action name="pending">-->
            <!--    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
            <!--        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
            <!--            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">pending</item>-->
            <!--            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Pending</item>-->
            <!--            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="quick/index/massStatus/status/Pending"/>-->
            <!--        </item>-->
            <!--    </argument>-->
            <!--</action>-->
            <!--<action name="process">-->
            <!--    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
            <!--        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
            <!--            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">process</item>-->
            <!--            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Under Process</item>-->
            <!--            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="quick/index/massStatus/status/Under Process"/>-->
            <!--        </item>-->
            <!--    </argument>-->
            <!--</action>-->
            <action name="edit">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                        <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.quick_quotes_columns_editor</item>
                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">editSelected</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.quick_quotes_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="quick_quotes_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.quick_quotes_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">quick_id</item>
                    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="tender/approve/inlineEdit"/>
                        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.quick_quotes_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">quick_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="quick_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="contact_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="company">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="validate-email" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>       

        <column name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">FM\Tender\Model\Quick\Source\Status</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>

                        <item name="default_filter" xsi:type="string">Old</item>

                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>

        </column>
        <column name="create_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>               
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="FM\Tender\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions2">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">quick_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>

    </columns>
    <container name="sticky">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/sticky/sticky</item>
                <item name="toolbarProvider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.listing_top</item>
                <item name="listingProvider" xsi:type="string">quick_approve_listing2.quick_approve_listing2.quick_quotes_columns</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </container>
</listing>
```

Action2.php

```
    const URL_PATH_EDIT = 'tender/approve/edit';
    const URL_PATH_DELETE = 'tender/index/delete';
    /** @var UrlBuilder */
    protected $actionUrlBuilder;
    /** @var UrlInterface */
    protected $urlBuilder;
    protected $authSession;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $editUrl;
    protected   $customersession;
    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     * @param string $editUrl
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customersession,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
        UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        $editUrl = self::URL_PATH_EDIT
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->actionUrlBuilder = $actionUrlBuilder;
        $this->customersession=$customersession;
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->editUrl = $editUrl;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        $custom2=$this->authSession;
        $user=$custom2->getCurrentUser();
        //$userid=$user->getUserId();
        $custom=$this->customersession;
        $val=$custom->getMyName();
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
              $data1=$dataSource['data']['items'];
              //$data2=$data1;
              foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $name = $this->getData('name');
                $new=$this->getData();
//                $nn=$new->addFieldToFilter('location',$custom);
                if (isset($item['quick_id'])) {
                    $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($this->editUrl, ['quick_id' => $item['quick_id']]),
                        'label' => __('Edit')
                    ];
                    // $item[$name]['delete'] = [
                    //     'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(self::URL_PATH_DELETE, ['quick_id' => $item['quick_id']]),
                    //     'label' => __('Delete'),
                    //     'confirm' => [
                    //         'title' => __('Delete ${ $.$data.contact_name }'),
                    //         'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a ${ $.$data.contact_name } record?')
                    //     ]
                    // ];
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **override `customer_listing.xml` in your theme**

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <filterSelect name="column_name" provider="${ $.parentName }" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select" template="ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select">
                <settings>
                    <options class="Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Options"/>  //Option Path
                    <caption translate="true">...Select...</caption>
                    <label translate="true">Label</label>
                    <dataScope>salesrep_name</dataScope>
                    <imports>
                        <link name="visible">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </filterSelect>
            <columns name="customer_columns">
                    <column name="column_name">
                        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Label</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </column>
            </columns>
    </listingToolbar>
```

> **Create `Option.php` file**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class Options implements OptionSourceInterface
{

    public $_options;

    public function toOptionArray() {
        return array(
            array('value' => 'helllo', 'label'=>'helllo'),
            array('value' => 'helllo1', 'label'=>'helllo1'),
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: that field not visible for admin grid ......

Comment: public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
}

can i  use here 

addFieldToFilter()  for $datasource

Comment: please attach code for understanding

Comment: i want the filter but that filed not showing in grid

Comment: add emil column in customer grid and add dynamic filter for that field ???

Comment: how i try dynamic filter

Comment: for my ui component

Comment: Element 'filterSelect', attribute 'provider': The attribute 'provider' is not allowed.